# Error importing from mysql to phpmyadmin #1064 ASC ion_auth

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Importing database from mysql throws an error. It says something wrong with syntax near ASC. But this is not happening when i add ion_auth script on separate way and not related to my tables. In other words, i think importing ion_auth script to mysql is giving errors. What should i do?

**Error**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_groups` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `group_id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_users_groups_users1_idx` (`user_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_users_groups_groups1_idx` (`group_id` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `uc_users_groups` ( ASC, `group_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users_groups_users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users_groups_groups1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`)
    REFERENCES `groups` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'ASC, `group_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users_groups_users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`us' en la linea 8
```

Comment: Remove `UNIQUE INDEX uc_users_groups ( ASC, group_id ASC),`. The `group_id` isn't a unique column anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this line:

```
UNIQUE INDEX `uc_users_groups` ( ASC, `group_id` ASC),
```

is supposed to be:

```
UNIQUE INDEX `uc_users_groups` (`user_id` ASC, `group_id` ASC),
```

The syntax error is because there's a column name missing before the first `ASC`.

Comment: Correct, but now ion_auth is redirecting me to the login page again and not entering... Looks like admin@admin / password doesn't work... anyway, i'll check as solved and will open another question

Comment: I have no idea what `ion_auth` is, but that seems like a totally separate problem.